# Flutter Android Development: How do I remove the gap left by the status bar and the black 'resize' area of the bottom of the screen?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

[image]

Hi,

I am working on an app for android using flutter and want to draw graphics on the screen. I have removed the status bar and would like to also remove the gap that it leaves and the bar at the bottom (see highlighted areas on graphic).

The target SDK is 33.

This is the code I have:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'design_2.dart';

class CardDisplayScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/carddisplayscreen';
  const CardDisplayScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
    ]);
     
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: [
        SystemUiOverlay.bottom
    ]);

    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Material(
      child: CustomPaint(
        size: Size(width, height),
        painter: Design2(),
      ),
      color: Colors.white,
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried wrapping Material in SafeArea, but this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set overlay empty array to hide status bar and bottom bar

- `overlays: []` : hide both status bar and bottom bar
- `overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.bottom]` : show only bottom bar
- `overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.top]`: show only status bar

ref: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemUiOverlay.html

i tried on my device, its work seem as per documentation describe. If still there a gap on your status bar even empty array, make sure its not your bezel screen